# MailChimp Sync Module vs PerceptiveMCAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mailchimp

can anyone please guide me towards using mailchimp with MVC 3..

I have made a simple demo from 
https://github.com/otint/MailChimp-MVC3-PerceptiveMCAPI which is perfectly fine.I can now show the lists i have.But i have a doubt that whether PerceptiveMCAPI 1.3.0 beta 2 will work smoothly with MCAPI 1.3 or not.I have seen some other wrapper MailChimp Sync Module.Should i go for it? Is it better...?

I am a complete newbie.I couldnt find much documentation too with using either of the wrappers i mean Sync Module or the PerceptiveMCAPI in MVC

Comment: bhargav - this API looks very promising. I've looked at a few which use handrolled RESTApi and none look this clean. I'd love to hear other thoughts on this implementation as it certainly does what it says on the tin. as for late breaking changes from beta->v1. that could easily happen but if the developers are responsive, i feel they'll give good guidence on those changes and therefore things should be smooth. I would however caution against using the beta versions in a live production environment for reasons you mention but also for the fact that the EULA may not permit such use.

Comment: actually, just looked at this on git. looks bl%%dy comprehensive. i now understand the question more re the beta status as it appears to have been in beta2 for over 9 months. will dig around as this is of huge interest to me too at the moment.

Comment: thanks Jim for the reply.So can you suggest the best way in integrating mailchimp with mvc3....?

Comment: well, this certainly is a very comprehensive library, so i think it should work very well for not only sync, but a host of other tasks too. you should experiment with a test account in mailchimp and add/sync via the library and just see how it goes for you (and report back :)).

Comment: well i am currently able to add subscribers(i give option to subscribe so a user can subscribe) from my mvc app which is updated in mailchimp site in my account.It is awesome to see it work :)

Comment: yes, in our last project, we had to add the subscriber via our crm, then do a batch export to mailchimp. this should solve that issue nicely. would love to share your exploits and will do likewise from my side once i've studied this a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been no changes in PerceptiveMCAPI for a long time and hence I decided to go with the other wrapper "MCAPI.NET"

Hope this helps someone